# new View.OnClickListener() is greyed out

Tags: java, android

I have a method with a setOnCLickListener, but the new View.OnClickListener() is greyed out. Trying to figure out what the error is exactly but when my app is supposed to launch it is supposed to ask for permission to access external storage which it is also not doing.

```
    private void createPDF() {
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
                Paint myPaint = new Paint();

                PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo1 = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(250, 400, 1).create();
                PdfDocument.Page myPage1 = myPdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo1);

                Canvas canvas = myPage1.getCanvas();

                canvas.drawText("Welcome to PDF", 40, 50, myPaint);
                myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage1);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/FirstPDF.pdf");

                try {
                    myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                myPdfDocument.close();


        }
    
    });
}
```

Comment: `Trying to figure out what the error is exactly` there's no error if it's letting you run the app, it just means the code you've added isn't needed/used or can be simplified

Comment: It's just the linter pushing you to use the latest Java Lambda functions so that the code looks cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Since i guess you're using AndroidStudio or similar, the solution is doing this:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void createPDF() {
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        PageInfo info = new PageInfo.Builder(250, 400, 1).create();
        Page page = myPdfDocument.startPage(info);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        canvas.drawText("Welcome to PDF", 40, 50, paint);
        document.finishPage(page);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/FirstPDF.pdf");

        try {
            myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        document.close();
    });
}
```

I changed the variable names for readability but that's up to you.
And also i removed the references to PdfDocument since they should be unnecessary if you import PdfDocument or the static references to Page and PageInfo. (I never used this class or package so i don't know which one it is.)